# Getting address out of range in MIPS assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am trying to reverse an array using only one array. When the index of high is less than or equal to low, I am supposed to keep switching the content of high and low. However, I am getting address out of range and am having trouble finding resources on how to fix it.

I'm supposed to only use one array while reversing the array. What am I doing wrong? Starred is where I am getting the error.

```
reverseArray:

        li $t6, 0 #head = first index of array
        la $s0, array
        li $t5, 4
        mult $s0, $t5
        mflo $t7 #tail = last index of array



swap:
    lw  $t6, 0($s0)
    **lw  $t4, 0($t7)**     

    sw  $t4, 0($s0)
    sw  $t6, 0($t7)

    add $t7, $t7, -4
    add $s0, $s0, 4

    sle $t1,$t7,$s0
    beq $t1,$0,swap
```

Comment: You are using an index as a pointer. You need to add the base address.

Comment: How would I do that? what is the base address? Sorry I am just starting out. @Jester

Comment: `$s0` is the base address, and you seem to multiply that by 4. That's wrong. You want to multiply element count by element size and add the base address.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want in `$t7` is the address of the last element of the array. Multiplying the base address by 4 is not going to give you that address. What you need to calculate is `array + (length-1)*4`.
So you need to know the length of the array. The code you've posted doesn't indicate that you know the length of the array, but let's say that you've got the length in register `$t6`. The calulation you need to perform then is:

```
addiu $t7,$t6,-1    # $t7 = length-1
sll   $t7,$t7,2     # $t7 = (length-1)<<2 == (length-1)*4
addu  $t7,$t7,$s0   # $t7 = (length-1)*4 + array

swap:
    lw  $t6, ($s0)
    lw  $t4, ($t7) 
    ... etc ...
```